# Let $y^2+x^2=1$ then $3(y^4+x^4)-2(y^6-x^6)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $y^2+x^2=1$ then $3(y^4+x^4)-2(y^6-x^6)=?$

My Try :
We know that $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$ so
$$(y^2)^2+(x^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-2(xy)^2$$
And also 
$$(y^2)^3-(x^2)^3=(y^2-x^2)^3+3x^2y^2(y^2-x^2)$$
And we know that $y^2-x^2=(y-x)^2+2xy$
now what ?

Comment: The title mentions $y^4-x^4$, but the first line of your post says $y^4+x^4$. Which one is it?

Comment: Note that the expression does not just depend on $x^2 + y^2$; take $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** You know that 
$$y^2=1-x^2$$

Then
$$3(y^4+x^4)-2(y^6-x^6)=3((1-x^2)^2+x^4)-2((1-x^2)^3-x^6)$$

Open the brackets and get an expression in $x$. If not all $x$'s cancel, since $x$ can take any value between $[-1,1]$, and what you obtain is a polynomial, that's the simplest expression in $x$ only possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the given sum, we have: $y^4(3-2y^2)= y^4(3-2 + 2x^2)= y^4(1+2x^2) = y^4+ 2y^4x^2$, and similarly $x^4(3-2x^2) = x^4+ 2x^4y^2 \implies S =  y^4-x^4 + 2x^2y^2(y^2-x^2) = (y^2-x^2)(1+2x^2y^2)= (1-2x^2)(1+2x^2(1-x^2))= (1-2x^2)(1+2x^2-2x^4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by expanding the right hand side...

$$\begin {align} 3(x^4+y^4) - 2(y^6-x^6) \\
&= 3x^4 + 3y^4 - 2y^6 + 2x^6 \\&= 3x^4 + 2x^6 + 3y^4 - 2y^6 \\&= x^4 + 2x^4 +2x^6 + y^4 +2y^4 -2y^6\\&= x^4 + 2 (x^4 + x^6) + y^4 + 2 (y^4 - y^6)\\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 (x^4 + x^6) + 2 (y^4 - y^6) \\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 x^4 (x^2 + 1) + 2 y^4 (1 - y^2) \\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 (x^4 + x^6 - y^4 -y^6) \\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 (x^4 (1+x^2) - y^4 (1+x^2)) \\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 ((1+x^2) (x^4 - y^4))\\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 ((1+x^2)\mathbf {(x^2 + y^2)}(x^2-y^2))\\&= x^4 + y^4 + 2 ((1+x^2)\mathbf{(1)}(x^2-y^2)) \\&= \mathbf {x^4 + y^4 + 2 (1+x^2)(x^2-y^2)}\\\end {align}$$

If we want the answer in terms of a single variable, make the appropriate substitutions for $x$ and $y$ as follows:

$$\begin{align} y^2 = 1-x^2, y^4 = (1-x^2)^2 \\ x^2 = 1-y^2, x^4=(1-y^2)^2 \\ \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is $$3(y^4+x^4)-2(y^6+x^6)=?$$

$x^6+y^6=(x^2)^3+(y^2)^3=(x^2+y^2)^3-3x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$

$x^4+y^4=(x^2)^2+(y^2)^2=?$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=x^2$ and $Y=y^2$ and consider then
$$Z=3(Y^2+X^2)-2(Y^3-X^3)\qquad \text{with}\qquad Y+X=1$$ Replace $Y=1-X$, expand the powers to get
$$Z=4X^3+1\implies Z=4x^6+1$$